# Extraer HH:MM de una tabla SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia, tengo un problema con el SQL Server, tengo un tabla en donde un campo tiene el formato **yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.000000** y quiero extraer su solo la hora y minutos (HH:MM) pero al poner esto **FORMAT(tabla.campo,'HH:mm')** me sale así 00:02 y no se si esta redondeando, porque en si la tabla donde hago la consulta su hora, minutos y segundos es 00:00:00 (la fechas si tiene numeros pero el tiempo es puro 0) y se necesita sacar el tiempo asi este en 00:00

Comment: Saludos. Prueba `SELECT convert(varchar, tabla.campo, 108)` (origen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449552/how-to-get-time-hhmmss-from-sql-query) y le quitas los últimos 3 caracteres. Considera que ese `campo`su dato es de tipo `DATETIME` (esto por que dices al incio formato `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.000000` espero no sea un texto; para tal caso deberás primero realizar la conversión de texto a + DATETIME`).

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que esta en formato `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.000000` lo dices literal, como una cadena concatenada con puntos y guiones?

Comment: ¿La columna es de tipo `VARCHAR` o `DATETIME`?

Comment: Hola RobertoLeOr , el SELECT convert(varchar, tabla.campo, 108) veo que si me ayudaria pero solo necesito 'HH:mm' y no segundos, hay forma de hacerlo? y si el campo es DATETIME donde voy a extraer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los campos datetime, no tienen formato. **Se almacenan en binario**. Y se muestran en un formato específico determinado, por la consulta, o el lenguaje de la conexión.

En el siguiente ejemplo, verás una variable tipo tabla, donde se alimenta una columna datetime, desde diferentes cadenas que se convierten al tipo de dato datetime, y luego la consulta, que los convierte al formato de salida.

```
begin tran
    declare @fechas table (fecha datetime)
    insert into @fechas (fecha)
    values
    ('20200101'),
    ('2020-01-01 09:03'),
    ('2020-01-01 09:04'),
    ('2020-01-01 09:05:12'),
    ('2020-01-01 09:06:00.015'),
    ('2020-01-01 09:07:00.997');
    
    set dateformat dmy
    insert into @fechas (fecha)
    values
    ('20200101'),
    ('01/02/2020 10:03'),
    ('01/02/2020 10:04'),
    ('01/02/2020 10:05:12'),
    ('01/02/2020 10:06:00.015'),
    ('2020-01-01 10:07:00.997');
    
    select fecha, CONVERT(varchar,fecha,8) ExtraerHHmm, format(fecha,'HH:mm') ConFormat
    from @fechas
commit tran
```

La función format se encarga de devolver un valor con formato, no de modificar su valor. Si aplicas esto con tu tabla, verás lo que te esta realizando FORMAT

```
select campo, CONVERT(varchar,campo,8) ExtraerHHmm, format(campo,'HH:mm') ConFormat
    from tabla
```

[image: Resultado]

[Format SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió tu aporte, igualmente lo de RobertoLeOr me funciono bien